# How to kill sub activities and bring activity to top of stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I have activity A that starts activity B which starts activity C:

A -> B -> C

When a user clicks on a button in activity C, I want to bring A to the top of the stack and take B & C completely out of the stack. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) flag on the intent to restart activity A.