# How to manipulate Activity back stack?

Tags: android, navigation, android-activity

I want to implement the following logic. I have 4 activites A, B, C and D.

The flow is A -> B -> C -> D

When the user navigates from A -> C he should be able to get back to the previous activities by pressing the back button. But after reaching D pressing the back button should take him to activity A. And pressing the back button againg should exit the application instead of taking him back to B / C / D. How do I do it.

Comment: This has been asked sooooo many times. Please do a simple search on this site.

Comment: Sorry for that I'll look into it and delete this post after finding an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you actually can manipulate the stack of application like your suggesting in your title.

My app runs in opengl so I never actually change form one Activity to another but I think the following principle will also work:

Why don't you call the Activity you want yourself ?

it is really straight forwards in the back button event to handle this.

on back pressed -> load activity you want

if your in activity A then exit

Comment: I thought of that too but the code some how doesn't look clean to me. I just found another answer <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408388/how-to-kill-sub-activities-and-bring-activity-to-top-of-stack">here</a>. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: no problem, I'm just glad you found the answer you needed ^^