# Activity Stack Management

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having trouble with my activity management. So I have activity **A** which goes to **B** and if you press the back button in **B** I want it to go to **A**, but there is also a case where **B** will finish and go to **C** and if I press the back button on **C** I want it to leave the app, basically the back stack is empty. What is the correct way to do this?

The only way I can see to do this is like this. When **A** starts **B** it calls finish() on **A** than on **B** I override the back button to start **A**, other wise if certain conditions are met call finish() on **B** and start **C**. Having to override the back button seems like I am doing something wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: this may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408388/how-to-kill-sub-activities-and-bring-activity-to-top-of-stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem through the user of the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP which was recommended to me by nibha on this post. [Another Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408388/how-to-kill-sub-activities-and-bring-activity-to-top-of-stack) and calling finish() in the appropriate places.