# How to finish an activity but I don't want go to previous activity (goto another activity)

Tags: android, android-activity

Let say there is an activity stack A -> B -> C -> D, from activity D, I want to finish it and go to activity A. It's ok to destroy activity B and C, btw. activity D can be accessed from activity A / B / C. So If I call activity D from B (A -> B -> D), I still want to go to activity A.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408388/how-to-kill-sub-activities-and-bring-activity-to-top-of-stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Activity D:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityD.this, ActivityA.class);
                intent.putExtra("param", param); //optional
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
```

Comment: After reach startActivity(intent), it will make new stack of activity right? I mean if activity A -> B -> D, in activity D startActivity (intent), it will be A -> B -> D -> A, and it will reach finish line if latest A is finished and will be like this activity A -> B in memory. What I want is if in activity D finish I want to reach to activity A, example activity A -> B -> D, it activity D is done, what I want is activity A -> B -> D destroyed and activity A is re-created or resume on activity A

Comment: ok. you add "finish()" after "startActivity()" in your activities and A, B and D activities will be destroyed

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:-

Call the Intent on the onBackpressd() method.It will go on that activity which you want.
Like:-

```
 @Override
    public void onBackpressd() {
        super.onBackpressd();
       Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityD.this, ActivityA.class);
                    intent.putExtra("param", param); //optional
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: After reach startActivity(intent), it will make new stack of activity right? I mean if activity A -> B -> D, in activity D startActivity (intent), it will be A -> B -> D -> A, and it will reach finish line if latest A is finished and will be like this activity A -> B in memory. What I want is if in activity D finish I want to reach to activity A, example activity A -> B -> D, it activity D is done, what I want is activity A -> B -> D destroyed and activity A is re-created or resume on activity A

Comment: Then do like this when you call  A -> B -> D  make sure to implement finish() method every time transition from one activity to another.

Comment: @KazutoRito when activity is called from one activity to another onPause